# How to Call Method of one activity from service in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I have one activity 'A' which extends mapActivity which calls service 'B', and Service 'B' which extends service. I'am getting Latitude and Longitude in service 'B'. Now i need to call the method in Activity 'A' and pass the Latitude and Longitude contineosly as soon as the location is updated. In that method I have code to display the Location. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant get reference of your **Activity** from **Service** unless you set a `STATIC` reference to it - which is highly not recommended and is considered to be a culprit for *memory leak* issues.

Instead, I would suggest you to make use of android's broadcasting mechanism using `context.sendBroadcast` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to Call Method of one activity from service in Android?

You don't.

Either:

- This should not be a `Service` in the first place (with all the logic within the activity), or
- Use `LocalBroadcastManager` to send a message from the service to the activity, or
- Use a `Messenger` to send a message from the service to the activity, or
- Use a `PendingIntent` created by `createPendingResult()` on the activity to send a message from the service to the activity, or
- Use a `ResultReceiver`, or the Otto library, or a variety of other means to send a message from the service to the activity